# How to count and group items by week

Tags: mysql

I have the following (MySQL) table called "sls_ord":

```
Sales           Total                   Date
joko susilo     Rp. 12.000.000;     24-May-2013
wenini          Rp. 13.000.000;     25-May-2013
Supardjo        Rp. 13.300.000;     20-May-2013
wenini          Rp. 20.300.000;     6-May-2013
joko susilo     Rp. 23.300.000;     8-May-2013
joko susilo     Rp. 24.000.000;     1-May-2013
```

How to count and group sales, total by week ?

1 more question please help me,, how to display the data in the next week automatically ???

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at any of the **Related** questions in the sidebar?

Comment: This is a good question, with a good answer. Unless someone finds a duplicate, it should be left open.

Comment: 1 more question please help me,, how to display the data in the next week
automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [YEARWEEK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek)

```
select sales, 
       yearweek(date) as week_date, 
       sum(total) as week_total
from sls_ord
group by sales, yearweek(date)
```

I assumed you mean to sum instead of counting.

Comment: I would probably group by the function instead of the alias to be on the safe side. Not entirely sure that it would make a difference.

Comment: To make it work in other DB engines you are right. It works for MySQL though

Comment: I hate MySQL so much. Mind changing it to make me feel warm and fuzzy inside?

Comment: Crap, would upvote but I've ran out of votes for the day.

Comment: Whaaaaat?! I roll my edit back! Right NOW! AAAAH!   :)

Comment: thanks Juergen you awesome

Comment: 1 more question please help me,, how to display the data in the next week automatically